# Select Field em Django dinamico

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a `<select>` with `<option>` from a directory. I read the directory, see the files that are there and I list the `<select>`.

The problem is that I'm having a hard time leaving the list as needed to pass it to ChoiceField in forms.py.

```
def choice1():
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    pasta =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/img/")
    c = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
    d = [i.replace(pasta,"") for i in c]
    return d

class FormItemAgenda(forms.Form):
    select1 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=choice1())
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. When I run the server and access to the page I see the following message:

```
ValueError at /listar-arquivos/
too many values to unpack
```

I researched it and apparently I must put the list generated in tuple format (tuple of tuples) but not a clue how to do this. Can anyone give a path for me to follow?

Comment: Please translate this to English.. First off, `choices=choice1()` should be `choices=choice1` It needs to be a callable, and not actually a called function. Also, can you edit the question with the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use brackets in form field-choices attribute.

Choice1 should return something like this

```
(('A', 'path/A'),
 ('B', 'path/B'),
)
```

This is what they mean by tuple of tuples.

Therefore, code should be something like -

```
def choice1():
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    pasta =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/img/")
    c = [os.path.join(pasta, nome) for nome in os.listdir(pasta)]
    d = [(str(i), i.replace(pasta,"")) for i in c]
    return tuple(d)

class FormItemAgenda(forms.Form):
    select1 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=choice1)
```

replace str(i) with anything you want your key to be.